# XCode 4 Crash but not sure why?

Tags: crash, xcode4

XCode4 just crash on me when I was testing my app without saying why. I put the crash log I found on the device below. The app runs fine in the simulation so I am thinking it's the memory problem? I check for leaks but there is nothing serious to it, also there is not memory warning call.

The log said "Saved crashreport to /Library/Logs/CrashReporter/LowMemory-2011-06-01-154632.plist" but I can't find it anywhere on my mac.

Please help,
Pondd

```
Jun  1 15:46:31 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.mondial.dva[0xd591]) Bug: launchd_core_logic.c:3795 (24506):0
Jun  1 15:46:31 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.mondial.dva[0xd591]) Bug: launchd_core_logic.c:920 (24506):3
Jun  1 15:46:31 unknown com.apple.debugserver-50[412] <Warning>: 1 [019c/1503]: error: ::read ( 4, 0x2ff8a9f0, 1024 ) => -1 err = Bad file descriptor (0x00000009)
Jun  1 15:46:31 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.mondial.dva[0xd591]) Bug: launchd_core_logic.c:3794 (24506):3
Jun  1 15:46:31 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.mondial.dva[0xd591]) Bug: launchd_core_logic.c:3202 (24506):10
Jun  1 15:46:31 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.mondial.dva[0xd591]) Working around 5020256. Assuming the job crashed.
Jun  1 15:46:31 unknown SpringBoard[28] <Warning>: Unable to delete job with label UIKitApplication:com.mondial.dva[0xd591]. Error: No such process
Jun  1 15:46:32 unknown ReportCrash[418] <Error>: Saved crashreport to /Library/Logs/CrashReporter/LowMemory-2011-06-01-154632.plist using uid: 0 gid: 0, synthetic_euid: 0 egid: 0
Jun  1 15:46:32 unknown configd[25] <Notice>: jetsam: kernel termination snapshot being created
Jun  1 15:46:32 unknown SCHelper[148] <Notice>: active (but IDLE) sessions
Jun  1 15:46:37 unknown SpringBoard[28] <Notice>: MultitouchHID(1cd11840) uilock state: 0 -> 1
Jun  1 15:46:41 unknown ReportCrash[420] <Notice>: Not saving Jetsam log because no data from the kernel.
Jun  1 15:46:41 unknown configd[25] <Notice>: jetsam: kernel termination snapshot being created
Jun  1 15:46:51 unknown ReportCrash[421] <Notice>: Not saving Jetsam log because no data from the kernel.
```

Comment: Accept answers of your previous questions

Comment: Go to your previous questions , plus the tick mark near the answer which helped you or guided you..That is the way to accept an answer..

Answer (score 0):

I found my LowMemory generated files through the organizer -> devices -> the device you are running on -> console -> right click on any of the logs on the left and select "Reveal in Finder"